# Can input value escape a JSON object?

Tags: xss, javascript, json

I am passing value from input filled directly into a script function inside a JSON object. I was thinking, is it possible that this input can escape this object and can lead to XSS or something.

```
<script>
...
function doSomething(item) {
data = {'content':item}
}
...
</script>

<input id="search" type="text" value="" oninput="doSomething(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: IMO what matters more than anything is what you do with the input value after. Being a search field, I assume it’s being sent to a server in your JS function. The server should always clean & sanitize that input. You can also serialize the input in JS first,to avoid breaking up the HTTP call in case of quote or other non-alphanumeric chars.

Comment: As TI said, *this* part is safe. It is what you do with it that matters. Write it back to the page? Now you have XSS to worry about. Send it to a server? SQLi, RCE, etc...

Comment: Thanks for painting clear picture. Now I know what can go wrong even if it looks safe now.